# Dynamic array in c used by function

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

Im trying to build a dynamic array  (according to the user input) using by a function. Im giving a small example of what i thought to do:

```
enter code here

int  main()
{
int *array;
int counter=0; ) //countes how many inputs we got

*array=dynamic_array(array,counter)

return 0;
}

int *dynamic_array(int *array, int counter){

int c=0;
while(c!=-1)
{
counter++;
array=(int *)realloc(arraya(counter)*sizeof(int));
}

return(array);
}
```

And another qustion, if i want to use &counter- which i cannot do it on c, how can i replace it?

Thank you.

Comment: Indent your code please. And what is the question? And please one question at a time.

Comment: Concerning your second question : what is `&counter-` supposed to do ? You should post a separate question and elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Your loop `while(c!=-1)` will never terminate as `c` is not modified in the loop. Your code won't compile with all those syntax and other errors.

Comment: What do you want to do with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really weird, so it's hard to tell what you actually want.

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// declare the dynamic_array function
int *dynamic_array(int *array, int counter);

int main()
{
  int *array = NULL;   // initialize to NULL (see realloc documentation)

  // allocate an array of 10 ints
  int counter = 10;
  array = dynamic_array(array, counter);
  array[0] = 12;
  array[1] = 34;

  // extend the array to 20 ints
  counter = 20;
  array = dynamic_array(array, counter);

  printf("array[0] = %d\n", array[0]);
  printf("array[1] = %d\n", array[1]);

  return 0;
}


int *dynamic_array(int *array, int counter)
{
  array = (int*)realloc(array, counter * sizeof(int));
  return(array);
}
```